# How to adjust padding in xaml label

Tags: xaml, label, padding

How can I make the top and bottom padding smaller in the following label? As I see it, the bounding box in much bigger than it needs to be, but the padding is set to 0, so it cannot be any smaller.

```
<Label Background="AliceBlue" Content="1800" FontSize="170" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Padding="0" />
```

Comment: Hello Bjarne, I have the same problem, did you find a solution? Anyone else knows a solution? You can best see this effect when using larger font sizes e.g. 20.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Margin.

With margin you can set the amount you want to go left, right, top, bottom

by this I mean `Margin="0,0,0,0"` that means. you have none what so ever.

it goes by the following: `Margin ="left, top, right, bottom`

so if I have `margin ="2,5,3,5"`

it means I have a margin 2 pixels in from the left, 5 pixels in from the top, 3 pixels from the right and 5 pixels up from the bottom.

Comment: If I am using margin margin ="5,0,0,0", than Label shifting toward right, but I want only text to move.

Answer (score 3):

Having just hit this where a border was around the label I set a negative margin.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <Label Margin="-5" Content="Unable to report/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

Padding does not exists in XAML on a `FrameworkElement`. Use Margin.

Padding can be applied to three elements: `Block`, `Border` and `Control` since these elements have an outer edge.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap the Label in a Layout for example StackLayout and give padding to that Layout, then Label will align accordingly. This code may helps you.

```
<StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label x:Name="TitleLbl"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

make custom renderer 
**PCL:**

```
 public class SALabel : Label
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Padding", typeof(Thickness), typeof(SALabel),default(Thickness));

        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
        }
}
```

**in android**

```
Control.SetPadding((int)saElement.Padding.Left, (int)saElement.Padding.Top, (int)saElement.Padding.Right, (int)saElement.Padding.Bottom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust label padding by setting margin and wrapping it inside a StackLayout

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Text="Login to your account" TextColor="White" Margin="10,10,10,10"  />
        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change to using TextBlock, then you can control the padding better. Label's purpose seems to be such that padding is fixed by its internal styling. See
"[How can I remove the margins around text in a WPF label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501380/how-can-i-remove-the-margins-around-text-in-a-wpf-label)".