# How can I remove the margins around text in a WPF label?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, label

I am trying to make a little virtual keyboard out of labels. The following is my keyboard in XAML (but with more than just 3 keys):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <Label Content="A" FontSize="12" MouseDown="KeyButton_Click" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <Label Content="B" FontSize="12" MouseDown="KeyButton_Click" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <Label Content="C" FontSize="12" MouseDown="KeyButton_Click" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem with this is that there is too much space surrounding the text in the labels, causing the keyboard to be much bigger than it needs to be. If I manually set the height and width of the labels, that will (1) not account for differences in fonts and (2) will cut of part of the letter rather than the top and left margins. Is there any other way to shrink these margins to be just about the same size as the text itself?

Comment: Did you try setting Padding to 0?

Comment: OT: if you plan on only using text in a `Label`, use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`. Less resources.

Comment: @Silvermind Thanks, put that as an answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `TextBlock` instead of `Label`

Comment: This is not the right answer. The `Label` is not equivalent to `TextBlock`. Consider `Label.Target`...

Comment: This sure does seem like the right answer in this case.

Comment: @Batman, it's only the right answer your DataContext is of the kind that is correctly displayed by a TextBlock.  For my part, the only reason I googled the problem was that I have the other kind.

Comment: No, `TextBlock` is different in many ways to `Label`. See https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/

Answer (score 72):

Set padding to 0.

I had the same problem. Upon examining the properties of a label in the properties window, I discovered the default padding of a label is 5. Setting it to 0 did the trick.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, given the question. That `Label` has a default padding of 5 is, ... strange...